# Printing with range and using separators (end=)

Tags: python

```
if i == 0:
   for ii in range(4):
      print((lengths[ii]) * '-', end='+')
print(fmtstr.format(list_l[i][0].upper(), list_l[i][1].upper(), list_l[i][2].upper(), list_l[i][3].upper()))
```

This prints out:

```
-------------------+-------------+--------------------+----+|        AAAAA        |    BBBBBB     |        CCCCC         | DDDD |
```

My two issues are that using the end command only places the '+' at the end of each set of 'lengths' and then joins it onto the next print command. How do I stop the end command during the last run so it doesn't add on the next set of data to be printed? Also, how do I make it so that separators are also at the start and end of the data?

Comment: Please clarify how you'd like to output to appear with an example

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is incomplete and unclear, I have to assume that your starting data looks something like this:

```
i = 0
lengths = [18,13,20,4]
list_l = [['aaaaa', 'bbbbbb', 'ccccc', 'dddd']]
fmtstr = "|        {}        |    {}     |        {}         | {} | "

if i == 0:
   for ii in range(4):
      print((lengths[ii]) * '-', end='+')

print(fmtstr.format(list_l[i][0].upper(), list_l[i][1].upper(), list_l[i][2].upper(), list_l[i][3].upper()))
```

and from what I can gather you want your end result to look like this:

```
+---------------------+---------------+----------------------+------+
|        AAAAA        |    BBBBBB     |        CCCCC         | DDDD |
+---------------------+---------------+----------------------+------+
```

You could collect a string instead of trying to create one on the fly and then print it on either side of your data:

```
s = "+"
if i == 0:
   for ii in range(4):
      s += (lengths[ii] * '-') + "+"

print(s)
print(fmtstr.format(list_l[i][0].upper(), list_l[i][1].upper(), list_l[i][2].upper(), list_l[i][3].upper()))
print(s)
```

Which gives:

```
+------------------+-------------+--------------------+----+
|        AAAAA        |    BBBBBB     |        CCCCC         | DDDD | 
+------------------+-------------+--------------------+----+
```

Clearly this isn't padded/centered right. But how can I help if I don't know your original data or the code in your loop?